# Exporting illustrator file and uploading to instagram blurry

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, image-quality, creative-cloud

I am having a dilemma with quality exporting from illustrator to  instagram. I don't know whether this is something I'm doing in illustrator or instagram. I create an artboard the same as an instagram post 1080px x 1080px and then place image in and scale it down because its larger than the post size. Then I export in save (for web legacy) and save as a png-24 which is fr[image]om what I read what you save as. I then bluetooth the image to my phone and upload from there.

When I view on my phone image quality is fine but on my 16 inch laptop its a bit blurry. I have looked at other instagram pages on my desktop and the image quality was good so am wondering what I am doing wrong. Just to reiterate the image placed in luustrator is larger then artboard and high quality jpeg.

This is what it looks like in instagram

Comment: The image example you posted is only 833 x 582 px. Make sure when you are viewing it that you aren't zooming in. Check you don't have system zoom enabled in your computer settings. It doesn't look blurry to me viewing at 100% (on a 17" laptop), but the text is too small to read easily. And the white text on red has severe jpeg compression artifacts, most likely caused by Instagram compressing the image too much.

Comment: Why are you using Illustrator if you’re just placing images? If you already have (raster) images and just need to scale them, that’s a Photoshop job, not an Illustrator job.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way a retroactive thing happens. Let me make a list and explain.*

**1.**
You have an artboard of 1080x1080px.

**2.**
I do not have an Illustrator right now to confirm if I need this step, but it is a good practice.

Make sure no element is outside the artboard. Hide whatever exceeds the artboard with a clipping path. And also, if you do not have an element all the way to the edge, you can also add a transparent (or white) rectangle as a background on all your post so you make sure you really have 1080x1080px.

**3.**
In Illustrator you should not change the resolution of the dialog box. Leave 72PPi and you will have a file of 1080x1080px.

**4.**
Now, you need to view this image on another program. It can be a web browser. Any program that will open it at 100% and show you the dimensions.
Here is your image and **it is not** 1080x1080px. It is 833x582px

[image]

If you are on windows you can use Irfanview as an image viewer.

---

If the image is wrong in this step, go back to your artboard (step2) and fix it.

If the image is really 1080x1080px continue. The image is fine, and there is no way anything previously done in Illustrator will retroactively modify this image.

---

**6.**
You send your file via Bluetooth. If the software is really only for transferring files it should not compress them or resample them.

**7.**

> When I view on my phone image quality is fine but on my 16 inch laptop its a bit blurry

You view it on your phone and it is ok. But this part I do not understand. If the image was ok, and I assume you have Illustrator on your 16 Inch laptop and was fine, how now is blurry. After doing what?

**8.**
If everything is ok up to this point, upload to your social network.

Keep in mind that all social networks will compress your image because they need to save space for images that will potentially be viewed millions of times, so they compress them when you upload them.

You can not do anything except prepare them to exact dimensions so you do not give any excuse for a resampling. They will be compressed but not resampled.

---

In your example, the font is too small, and you can also add a bit of sharpening.
But it has not a square proportion. So, you either did not prepare it right from start or you cropped it somewhere.